# invariant violation could not find store in the context of connect(app)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to deal with Redux inside the root file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore,bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {View} from "@shoutem/ui/components/View";
import { Spinner } from '@shoutem/ui';
import { Login } from './Actions/user';
import { createProfile } from './Actions/profile';
import Nav from './Screens/Nav';
import reducers from './Reducers';

export class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        console.disableYellowBox = true;
    }

    async iniRoute()
    {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Profile:user');
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.iniRoute().then(data => {
            if (data)
            {
                this.props.Login(data.username,data.email);
                this.props.createProfile(data.name , data.username , data.email , data.birthday , data.password , data.location);
                this.setState({loading:false});
            }
            else
            {
                this.setState({loading:false});
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store = {createStore(reducers)}>
                <View>
                    {!this.state.loading && <Nav />}
                    {this.state.loading && <Spinner />}
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({
      Login,
      createProfile,
    }, dispatch)
  );

 export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

it is firing the following error

> Invariant Violation could not find store in the context of connect(app)

I may write some wrong codes because my experience with Redux is not very good ,

in this case - can anyone tell me how to achieve this without facing these errors.

Comment: try moving `store = {createStore(reducers)}` from render method to global as `const myStore = createStore(reducers)` and use it as  `<Provider store = {myStore}>`

Answer (score -1):

App.js should be the one that is wrapped with Provider.
Provider is the one that gives your application the store instance, and only then connect can fetch the store. So in essence you're trying to read the store before you created it.
So assuming you have an index.js renders the App.js you should change it from

```
//Your code here
//wrappers on App
<App/>
//wrappers on App
//Your code here
```

to

```
//Your code here
<Provider>
   //wrappers on App
   <App/>
   //wrappers on App
</Provider>
//Your code here
```

You can find a basic tutorial by searching for Provider on Google. Here is the link https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: in the reducer function , it takes 2 params state and action , when I log action - it logs : {type: "@@redux/INITt.u.q.e.f"} , what is this - that's totally wrong - the action creator not send this one

Comment: Without seeing the complete code and the error it is hard to say what the problem is. If you refer the tutorial that i have mentioned then you should be able to setup a redux environment. Once setup, dispatch while using only react-redux should always be a JavaScript object: {type: 'DUMMY_TYPE', action: 'dummy'}
action can be an object too: {type: 'DUMMY_TYPE', action: {property: 'dummy'}}